# how to get selected companies in a pdf report

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-14

as mentioned in the title, I want to get the selected companies (in a multi-company DB) inside a report, I know that it can be done in python using:

```
select_companies = self.env['res.company'].browse(self._context.get('allowed_company_ids'))
```

[image]

but in qweb I don't have `self` (the record), is there another way to get the context?

NB: I will use them in `t-if`
Odoo v14

Comment: Please try: request.env['res.company'].browse(request._context.get('allowed_company_ids')) in qweb .

Comment: can you explain what is `request`?

Comment: you can browse object using request in qweb.

Comment: Your hint about the template is helping. You're not extending a Report for PDFs but a BI (business intelligence) report template.

Answer (score 2):

In **document reports** (QWeb) you usually got `doc` or `o` which represents the record you want to print/render. That's usually (except in very less situations) a normal Odoo recordset with all the things you can use in Odoo's python business logic code. So just try:

```xml
<span t-esc="o.env.context.get('allowed_company_ids', 'sorry nothing here')" />
```

That should print/render the list of company IDs. If that's working you can also use it in `t-if`s and other QWeb control elements.

In **business intelligence** reports (QWeb again) it depends on how the report is called. In the comment the template `account_reports.line_template` is mentioned, which uses `context.get()` already. But that must not mean that this context is the normal context. But it's worth a try. You have to dig into the report python code, to find out what is present in the context or how to manipulate it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I already tried that, but after verification I see that I have no `doc` neither `o`, I am inheriting  `account_reports.line_template`

Comment: in `account_reports.line_template` I see there is `<t t-if="not context.get('print_mode')">`, does it mean I can use `context.get('allowed_company_ids', 'sorry nothing here')` ?